# Appending a string to a tinyMCE instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, append

I need to append a string (an img tag) to a tinyMCE editor instance.

I was doing it like this:

```
$("#textboxhiddenbytinymce").append( string );
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

with no luck. I was wondering if:

There is a direct method for adding an arbitrary string (I need complete control over it) to an instance of tinyMCE I understand that the way I'm doing it is wrong since tinyMCE works indipendently to the "original" textarea.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this will work is if you use the [jQuery Plugin version](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/jQuery_Plugin). Luckily it's easy to convert an existing tinyMCE.init block to use jQuery:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('textarea#tinymce').tinymce({
        script_url: 'tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        // and all your existing config
});
```

Then you can access the $('textarea#tinymce') object and [edit it as you would a normal element](http://blog.moxiecode.com/2010/01/26/more-jquery-goodness/).

Hope this answer is still helpful to someone a year after the question was posted!

Comment: existing config refer to ? I want to append template_replace_values to existing tinymce. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of TinyMCE (version 4 at the moment) put their content in an iframe.  After you find the id of that iframe, something similar to the following can be used:

```
var id_of_iframe = '';
$('#' + id_of_iframe).contents().find('#tinymce').append(string);
```