# how to jquery onclick append text to end of TINYMCE textarea

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to click a word in the page that will append a word at the end of a `<textarea>`. What I have works fine on normal textareas but I can't find the proper way to do this in TinyMce.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>

<Idea2>Idea2</Idea2>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$('Idea2').click(function() { 
$('#DiscussionX1').val($('#DiscussionX1').val()+'\n\r newCharter'); 

});
</script>
```

I've been told this below would be something like what I need but, I don't know how to deploy it to my code.

```
    $('.mceContentBody').tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertContent',false);
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This answer is probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5993639/1718121

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.mceContentBody').tinymce().execCommand(
        'mceInsertContent', 
        false, 
        {
         'value': 'newCharterOrWhateverHere', 
         'anothervalue' :'forTheSakeOfCompleteness'
        }
 );

 function mceInsertContent(object) {
      // get content of the current textarea and add the new value you want
      var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'}) + object.value;
      tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content, {format : 'raw'});
 }
```

Comment: That looks interesting. I'll scope it out and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more about how these plugs in together? Thank you.